# Jquery - Preload big image

Tags: jquery, ajax

how do I preload a large image (2 mb)?

I've tried it all already, type:

```
$ ("#image"). load (function () {
}
```

Comment: http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/

Comment: It looks like you're missing some arguments. You need to pass the URL as the first parameter.

Comment: What is #image? is that id of `img` or Div tag?

Comment: I'm wanting to preload the background, this was just an example of what I tried, I tried with the div tag and invisible duplicate image and everything else ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preloading images with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery)